# How to use other attacks in The Lion King on SNES?

Tags: snes, the-lion-king

How do I use special attacks in The Lion King on SNES?
In the instruction booklet, It says: "Make Simba pounce. B button and land on top of enemy." and "Jumping slash as Adult Simba. B button and the Y button" but I cannot use any of these. Do I need to land on some special part of the enemy sprite? How long do I need to wait between the B and Y Button presses?
I tried multiple combinations for over two hours now, and I still don't know how to do these consistently.